# Reload page after POST request success with hooks

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks

I want to reload page (call get request again) after POST request success with hooks. Let's say I have a post reducer

```
const post = {
    isLoading: false
    isSaving: false
    data: any
    error: string
}
```

Normally when I create a class component

```
componentDidMount() {
    this.props.getPost()
}

componentDidUpdate(prevProps) {
 // When create new Post successfully, get post again
 if (prevProps.post.saving && this.props.post.saving) {
  this.props.getPost()
 }
}
```

But when do the same thing with hooks, I know how to fetch the post but don't know how to reload it after creating a new one successfully

```
// Get post on did mount
React.useEffect(() => getPost(), [])
```

Could you guys show me how to do that? Thank you very much

Answer (score 0):

You can copy componentDidUpdate functionality and especially `prevProps.post.saving && this.props.post.saving` using `useEffect` hook this way:

Assuming you have `getPost` and `saving` props

```js
React.useEffect(() => saving && getPost(), [saving])
```

Given this code, your effect will rerun when `saving` changes it's value.

Answer (score 0):

I end up with this code :

```
const prevSaving = usePrevious(post.saving)
    useEffect(() => {
        if (prevSaving && !post.saving) {
            getPost()
        }
    }, [post.saving])
```

And this is the usePrevious hooks

```
export const usePrevious = value => {
    const ref = React.useRef()

    React.useEffect(() => {
        ref.current = value
    }, [value])

    return ref.current
}
```